# Cookie not kept when moving from html to perl page

Tags: cookies, web

One of my clients uses Sellerdeck as their shopping cart solution. I am currently implementing a service for them that relies heavily on cookies.

The cookie is set on a product page which has a URI that is something like `http://www.mydomain.co.uk/retail/acatalog/A11-Insect-Net.html`. When I browse around the site, I can see the cookie set on all pages, like it is supposed to.

Then when I go into the checkout process, Sellerdeck apparently starts using perl, because the URI changes to something like `http://www.mydomain.co.uk/cgi-bin/retail/ca001000.pl`. The weird thing is that, although we're still on the same domain, I can't see the cookie. When I go back to the product pages it is there again.

Doe anyone know why this may be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the cookie was tied to a specific path and not to `/`. Fixed now.